# Automatically add an "ID" field to each new document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Each time a new document is created, the document ID is generated automatically by firebase.
But how to make the "id" field automatically created in each document, which will have the same value as the document id generated by firebase?

I tried the chatgpt generated code that I pasted in the rules in Firebase but it didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried doing the simplest thing and just writing the ID into the document after it's created?  Did something not work the way you expect with that?  It would be helpful to know what programming language you're working with and the code you have so far.  Nothing is going to happen "automatically" here - you're going to have to write code for it somehow, and there are potentially many ways to get this job done.  You should know that you don't have to accept Firestore's document IDs.  You can randomly generate a string yourself and use that to add the document.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built in to Firebase for this, but the third code snippet in the documentation on [adding a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) shows how to separate the creation of the ID from the writing of the data:

> In some cases, it can be useful to create a document reference with an auto-generated ID, then use the reference later. For this use case, you can call doc():
>
> ```
> import { collection, doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 
>
> // Add a new document with a generated id
> const newCityRef = doc(collection(db, "cities"));
>
> // later...
> await setDoc(newCityRef, data);
> ```

Based on this, you can include the document ID as a field in the `setDoc` operation:

```
setDoc(newCityRef, { id: newCityRef.id, /* other data here */ });
```

For another example of this, see: [Firestore add Document ID to Data via functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74581875/firestore-add-document-id-to-data-via-functions)

---

Alternatively you can build a simple [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) that [triggers when a document is created](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) and then adds the ID field on the server.